# select the rows by intersection of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like

```
In [67]: df                                                                                                         
Out[67]: 
   id         ts
0   a 2018-01-01
1   a 2018-01-02
2   a 2018-01-03
3   a 2018-01-04
4   a 2018-01-05
5   a 2018-01-06
6   a 2018-01-07
7   a 2018-01-08
8   b 2018-01-03
9   b 2018-01-04
10  b 2018-01-05
11  b 2018-01-06
12  b 2018-01-07
13  b 2018-01-08
14  b 2018-01-09
15  b 2018-01-10
16  b 2018-01-11
```

How can I extract the part where `a` and `b` has a same `ts`?

```
   id         ts
2   a 2018-01-03
3   a 2018-01-04
4   a 2018-01-05
5   a 2018-01-06
6   a 2018-01-07
7   a 2018-01-08
8   b 2018-01-03
9   b 2018-01-04
10  b 2018-01-05
11  b 2018-01-06
12  b 2018-01-07
13  b 2018-01-08
```

---

There might be many unique `id` beside `a` and `b`. I want all the intersection of column `ts`.

> what would be the expected output with an additional row of `c 2018-01-04`?

It would be

```
a 2018-01-04
b 2018-01-04
c 2018-01-04
```

Comment: Was would be the expected output with an additional row of `c 2018-01-04`?

Comment: Okay, updated the answer to account for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), so get missing values for different datetimes, remove them by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and then filter original DataFrame by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='ts', columns='id', aggfunc='size').dropna()

df = df[df['ts'].isin(df1.index)]
print (df)

   id          ts
2   a  2018-01-03
3   a  2018-01-04
4   a  2018-01-05
5   a  2018-01-06
6   a  2018-01-07
7   a  2018-01-08
8   b  2018-01-03
9   b  2018-01-04
10  b  2018-01-05
11  b  2018-01-06
12  b  2018-01-07
13  b  2018-01-08
```

Test if added new `c` row:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='ts', columns='id', aggfunc='size').dropna()

df = df[df['ts'].isin(df1.index)]
print (df)
   id          ts
3   a  2018-01-04
9   b  2018-01-04
17  c  2018-01-04
```

Comment: @yatu - I understand `How can I extract the part where a and b has a same ts` this way, I hope correct.

Answer (score 1):

To keep *only* the intersecting values, you could take the [`groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) of `ts`, and check the which of these groups have a size equal to the amount of unique values in `ts`. Then use the result to index the dataframe.

Checking on the proposed dataframe, and the additional row `c  2018-01-04`, this would return only the intersecting dates in `ts`:

```
s = df.groupby(df.ts).size().eq(df.id.nunique())
df[df.ts.isin(s[s].index)]


   id          ts
3   a  2018-01-04
9   b  2018-01-04
16  c  2018-01-04
```